# gpg-agent keeps saving pin for a smartcard

Tags: gnupg, smartcard, enigmail

I've found today, that enigmail is decrypting a message without asking me for the smart card's PIN. It is asking only once, and then not ask at all.

this is my gpg-agent.conf:

```
default-cache-ttl 0
max-cache-ttl 0
no-allow-external-cache
ignore-cache-for-signing
```

scdaemon.conf:

```
card-timeout 0
deny-admin
```

gpg.conf is empty

gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.16

libgcrypt 1.7.3-beta

Gnome keyring is stopped. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does setting the timeout to 1 second not prompt you for every attempt?

Answer (score 16):

I've been looking into this myself. I want to be prompted to enter my PIN every time I request my smart card (Yubikey in my case) to do a sign/encrypt/auth operation. It is possible to enable this behaviour for signing by enabling `forcesig` through `gpg2 --card-edit` (see [GnuPG documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/howtos/card-howto/en/ch03s03.html)):

```
forcesig   toggle the signature force PIN flag
```

but not for encryption and authentication operations.

[This post on the GnuPG mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2006-September/029321.html) by Werner Koch himself seems to imply that the smart card itself is caching the PIN.

I will look into this further (perhaps send an email to the GnuPG mailing list) and update this answer if I find any more information.

Comment: I suggest enabling touch verification (a yubikey setting) on all operations. That seems to provide better security, since it cannot be remembered or phished.

Comment: You can just stop and restart your `gpg-agent` every x # of mins to force pin re-entry.

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround I found is to run a bash script in the background that reloads the gpg-agent every X second. Specifically, append this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
while true; do gpgconf --kill gpg-agent; sleep X; done &
```

where X denotes how long, in seconds, you want the pin to be stored for. Note that this script will also kill any other gpg related processes, so it's only a quick fix if you use gpg mostly for pinentry processes.

This will run in the background, but it can be accessed by using the `jobs`command, and similarly stopped using the `kill` command.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research `card-timeout` is a dummy parameter and was never meant to force a time limit on caching the smartcard pin.

Some interesting quotes from [this bug report](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3383).

> Let me explain the situation.
>
> In scdaemon manual, it explained as scdaemon will be powering down the smartcard by the value specified.
>   But, it never has been implemented as described.
>
> In 2.0, it was a variable to control scdaemon to allow DISCONNECT command.
>   In 2.1, scdaemon has been improved to allow DISCONNECT command always.
>
> Thus, it is true, this variable has no effect in 2.1.

and

> It has been a dummy option for years (since GnuPG 2.1). For the record, I write more detail here.
>
> It never worked as these bug reporter expected (directly control access from scdaemon to card by time out), it only changed the behavior of DISCONNECT command. A user required to issue DISCONNECT command anyway and the option could change how DISCONNECT was done. <-- This is 2.0.
>
> Since 2.1, DISCONNECT command works well always, regardless of this option.